# Why are List and String identifiers named "xs" (in Scala and other languages)?

Tags: scala, naming-conventions, identifier

A lot of sample Scala code contains Strings and Collections named "xs".
Why xs?

Examples:

```
var xs = List(1,2,3)
val xs = "abc"
```

Comment: Related (but probably not a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564758/does-functional-programming-mandate-new-naming-conventions

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Basically it's a naming convention that originated in LISP. The rationale behind it is that:

1. X is a common placeholder name.
2. XS is pronounced X'es, i.e "many X".

Comment: The convention is actually extended to multi-dimensional structures. For example, xss may be a list of lists, and xsss may be an array of arrays of arrays.

Comment: And why not use proper and meaningful names?

Answer (score 31):

[`xs` is the plural of `x`.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_read_Haskell#Tip:_the_-s_and_m-_habits)

Answer (score 18):

Apart from the fact that `xs` is meant to be a plural of x as [@Ken Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938031/why-are-list-and-string-identifiers-named-xs-in-scala-and-other-languages/3938072#3938072) points out, it's also relevant to note how languages like Scala structure `List`. `List` is structured as a linked list, in which the container has a reference to the first item and to the rest of the list.

[image]

The `::` operator (called [cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)) constructs the list as:

```
42 :: 69 :: 613 :: Nil
```

The `::` when appearing in pattern matching also extracts a list into the first item and the rest of the list as follows:

```
List(42, 69, 613) match {
  case x :: xs => x
  case Nil => 0
}
```

Since this pattern appears everywhere, readers can infer that `xs` implies "the rest of the list."

Comment: I mentally pronounce the "xs" as "excess", as in "the rest".

Answer (score 8):

I've seen this name used for list variables in functional programming tutorials, but not strings (except where a string is considered a list of characters).

It's basically a dummy name used in examples. You might name a scalar variable `x` while a list would be `xs`, since `xs` is the plural of `x`. In production code, it's better to have a more descriptive name.

You might also see this in code which pattern matches with lists. For example (in OCaml):

```
let rec len l =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | x :: xs -> 1 + len xs
```

A more descriptive pair of names might be `first :: rest`, but this is just an example.

Comment: I tend to use same convention in production, for example "order" and "orders" ;)

Comment: I think the use of x an xs is perfect for production code, too. The domain meaning should be inside the name of the result variable.